# Azure Maps API - Limit By Type

Tags: azure, api, azure-maps

I have implemented the Azure Maps search at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddress but I want to get a list of only certain "types".
In the results below, the type is "Street", but I am interested in returning only those where the type matches "MunicipalitySubdivision".

If I do a call to this service, the API returns results in blocks of 10 by default (which can be upped to 200), and gives a TotalResults field as well. It is possible to iterate through (for example) 50,000 results 200 at a time by providing a results offset startIndex parameter in the API, but this doesn't seem like the most efficient way to return just results of one type.

Can anyone suggest anything?

```
{
  "type": "Street",
  "id": "GB/STR/p0/1199538",
  "score": 5.07232,
  "address": {
    "streetName": "Hampton Road",
    "municipalitySubdivision": "Birmingham, Aston",
    "municipality": "Birmingham",
    "countrySecondarySubdivision": "West Midlands",
    "countrySubdivision": "ENG",
    "postalCode": "B6",
    "extendedPostalCode": "B6 6AB,B6 6AE,B6 6AN,B6 6AS",
    "countryCode": "GB",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "countryCodeISO3": "GBR",
    "freeformAddress": "Hampton Road, Birmingham",
    "countrySubdivisionName": "England"
  },
  "position": {
    "lat": 52.50665,
    "lon": -1.90082
  },
  "viewport": {
    "topLeftPoint": {
      "lat": 52.50508,
      "lon": -1.90015
    },
    "btmRightPoint": {
      "lat": 52.50804,
      "lon": -1.90139
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't an option to limit the results as you requested other than to scan the results programmatically. If the address information you have is structured (you have the individual pieces) and is not a freeform string, then using the structured geocoding service would allow you to specify the type right request when passing in the address parts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddressstructured